# Not recognizing directory in python

Tags: python, selenium, directory, geckodriver

I am having a go at using selenium for the first time and have hit a slight issue. I have downloaded selenium and the latest verison of geckodriver and followed the instructions I found online to install it all.

When I input the code, I am having an issue with it recognising the directory that the geckodriver.exe file is in. I'll add my code below.

```
path = r'C:/Users/bubbl/Downloads/geckodriver-v0.29.1-win64/geckodriver.exe' #Path to Firefox Driver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(path)
driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com/screener/")
button = driver.find_element_by_id('screener-export-data')
button.click()
```

When I press run, I get the following error message.

```
NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:/Users/bubbl/Downloads/geckodriver-v0.29.1-win64/geckodriver.exe'
```

I have done some searching and seen that it could be to do with the / slashes. I have tried the following other options, all of which give me the same error message.

```
'C:/Users/bubbl/Downloads/geckodriver-v0.29.1-win64/geckodriver.exe'
'C:\\Users\\bubbl\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.29.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe'
```

I also tried the following code

```
'C:\Users\bubbl\Downloads\geckodriver-v0.29.1-win64\geckodriver.exe'
```

Which gave the following error message

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Any ideas on what I can try?

Update: I've managed to fix the problem. I moved the geckodrive.exe file into another folder and that has fixed the problem. This is the format that I used in the end.

```
path = r"C:\Users\bubbl\Documents\Python"
```

Comment: Have you unzipped the folder? It looks like zipped folder.

Comment: Yes. I've double checked the location and that's pointing to the unzipped folder. The zipped folder has a .zip after win64.

Comment: Replace with backslash and use the double quotes then it will  convert normal string to raw string `path = r"C:\Users\bubbl\Downloads\geckodriver-v0.29.1-win64\geckodriver.exe"`

Comment: Unfortunately that gives me the same error messsage that the directory name is invalid.

Comment: It could be issue with String. Try `path="C:\\Users\\bubbl\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.29.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe"`. Can you use double quotes.

Comment: That's also giving the same error message. I'm wondering if it's because it's not actually a directory as I've got the file name in there. But if I remove the file name then it says     WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH

Comment: I seem to have fixed it. I moved the .exe file into another folder that I had used in previous code and now it works.

Comment: May be access issue